# Unable to grab titles from the innermost pages of a website

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, promise, request

I've created a script below to collect all the links under province from this [website](https://egpostal.com/en/p/all), then visit individual links to collect all the links under office, and finally scrape the title from the target pages.

The script gets stuck after scraping the title from the first link. I'm very new to Promise, so I can't figure out the issue.

Here's what I came up with:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const link = 'https://egpostal.com/en/p/all';
const base_link = 'https://egpostal.com/en/';

const landing_page_links = [];
const inner_page_links = [];

let getLinks = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(link, function(error, response, html) {
            let $ = cheerio.load(html);
            if (error) return reject(error);
            try {
                $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
                    landing_page_links.push(base_link + $(this).find("a").attr("href"));
                });
                resolve(landing_page_links);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        });
    });
};

let getInnerLinks = (links) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let url of links) {
        request(url, function(error, response, html) {
            let $ = cheerio.load(html);
            if (error) return reject(error);
            try {
                $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
                    inner_page_links.push(base_link + $(this).find("a").attr("href"));
                });
                resolve(inner_page_links);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
      });
    }
  });
};

let FetchTitle = (links) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let url of links) {
        request(url, function(error, response, html) {
            let $ = cheerio.load(html);
            if (error) return reject(error);
            try {
                resolve($(".home-title > h2").eq(0).text());
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        })
      }
  })
}

getLinks().then(resultList => {
    getInnerLinks(resultList).then(resultSet => {
        FetchTitle(resultSet).then(title =>{
            console.log(title);
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [**request** is deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), so you should avoid this package. Since you want to work with *promises*, I recommend you to use [**axios**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) instead.

Honestly, if I were you, I would use a crawling library to make things easier and more robust. But I guess this is more or less a coding challenge, so I am going to take your code 'as is' and tweak it to make it work.

The main problem here is with `getInnerLinks` where you resolve your promise within a **request** callback, which is itself within a loop. If the first iteration is OK, your script will jump to the next step through `.then()` in the main promise chain. So, in fact, it is more logical to resolve your promise after the loop. But given that all requests are asynchronous, you need to wait. `setTimeout()` is useful in this case to run some tests. Now the question is: how much time do you have to wait? Well... A reliable and safe solution when you play with many promises is to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Moreover, a promise for `FetchTitle` is overkill. You can directly put a `console.log()` in there to print titles.

Here is the code:

```js
const axios = require('axios'),
      cheerio = require('cheerio');

const link = 'https://egpostal.com/en/p/all',
      base_link = 'https://egpostal.com/en/';

const landing_page_links = [],
      inner_page_links = [];

let getLinks = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get(link)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        let $ = cheerio.load(data);

        try {
          $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
            landing_page_links.push(base_link + $(this).find('a').attr('href'));
          });

          resolve(landing_page_links);
          console.log('Landing page OK');
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
};

let getInnerLinks = links => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let requests = [];

    for (let url of links) {
      requests.push(axios.get(url)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          console.log(`Shallow request: ${url}`);

          let $ = cheerio.load(data);

          $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
            inner_page_links.push(base_link + $(this).find('a').attr('href'));
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
      );
    }

    Promise.all(requests)
      .then(() => {
        resolve(inner_page_links);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};

let FetchTitle = links => {
  for (let url of links) {
    axios.get(url)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(`Deep request: ${url}`);

        let $ = cheerio.load(data);
        console.log($('.home-title > h2').eq(0).text());
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}

getLinks()
  .then(resultList => getInnerLinks(resultList))
  .then(resultSet => FetchTitle(resultSet))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of web-scrapping good fit by [`scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/) on Python.

Steps

```
$scrapy startproject egpostal
$cd egpostal
$scrapy genspider post-office https://egpostal.com
```

It will create files

```
D:\temp\test>tree /F
Folder PATH listing for volume DATA
Volume serial number is 16D6-338C
D:.
└───egpostal
    │   scrapy.cfg
    │
    └───egpostal
        │   items.py
        │   middlewares.py
        │   pipelines.py
        │   settings.py
        │   __init__.py
        │
        ├───spiders
        │   │   post_office.py
        │   │   __init__.py
        │   │
        │   └───__pycache__
        │           post_office.cpython-310.pyc
        │           __init__.cpython-310.pyc
        │
        └───__pycache__
                items.cpython-310.pyc
                settings.cpython-310.pyc
                __init__.cpython-310.pyc
```

Among this files we will touch only two files (items.py and post_office.py)

Overwrite two files with this code

#### post_office.py

```
import scrapy

from egpostal.items import EgpostalItem

class PostOfficeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'post-office'
    start_urls = ['https://egpostal.com/en/p/all']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url, 
                callback = self.url_parse
            )

    # parsing https://egpostal.com/en/p/all level
    def url_parse(self, response):
        base_link = 'https://egpostal.com/en/'
        provinces = []
        for a in response.xpath('//tbody//tr//a'):
            provinces.append({
                'province': a.xpath('./text()').extract_first(),
                'url': base_link + a.xpath('./@href').extract_first()
            })
        for province in provinces:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                province['url'], 
                callback = self.parse_province,
                # 1st parameter
                cb_kwargs=dict(province=province['province'])
            )

    # parsing province level
    def parse_province(self, response, province):
        base_link = 'https://egpostal.com/en/'
        offices = []
        for a in response.xpath('//tbody//tr//td//a'):
            offices.append({
                'province' : province,
                'office': a.xpath('./text()').extract_first(),
                'url': base_link + a.xpath('./@href').extract_first()
            })
        for office in offices:
            request = scrapy.Request(
                office['url'], 
                callback = self.parse_postal_office,
                # 1st parameter
                cb_kwargs=dict(office=office['office'])
            )
            request.cb_kwargs['province'] = province    # 2nd parameter
            yield request

    # parsing office level
    def parse_postal_office(self, response, office, province):
        title = response.xpath('//div[@class="home-title"]//h2/text()').get().strip()
        loader = EgpostalItem()  # Here you create a new item each iteration
        loader['province'] = province
        loader['office'] = office
        loader['title'] = title
        yield loader
```

#### items.py

```
import scrapy

class EgpostalItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    province = scrapy.Field()
    office = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

#### Run it with save into result.json

if you success those step, you can see some log in terminal.
(*note -O is capital)

```
$ scrapy crawl post-office -O result.json
```

```
[
{"province": "Ismailia", "office": "Sheikh Zayed", "title": "Sheikh Zayed Post Office"},
{"province": "Ismailia", "office": "Channel", "title": "Channel Post Office"},
{"province": "Ismailia", "office": "Balwah", "title": "Balwah Post Office"},
{"province": "Ismailia", "office": "Eye twig", "title": "Eye twig Post Office"},
{"province": "Ismailia", "office": "Nvich", "title": "Nvich Post Office"},
{"province": "Ismailia", "office": "Manshyet martyrs", "title": "Manshyet martyrs Post Office"},
{"province": "Ismailia", "office": "Fanara", "title": "Fanara Post Office"},
{"province": "Ismailia", "office": "Evacuation camp", "title": "Evacuation camp Post Office"},
{"province": "Dakahlia", "office": "Nqath", "title": "Nqath Post Office"},
{"province": "Dakahlia", "office": "Kafr El Allam", "title": "Kafr El Allam Post Office"},
{"province": "Alexandria", "office": "San Stefano", "title": "San Stefano Post Office"},
{"province": "Beheira", "office": "White housing", "title": "White housing Post Office"},
{"province": "Beheira", "office": "Kvraldoar fabric", "title": "Kvraldoar fabric Post Office"},
{"province": "Beheira", "office": "Kvraldoarveray", "title": "Kvraldoarveray Post Office"},
{"province": "Beheira", "office": "Kvraldoar", "title": "Kvraldoar Post Office"},
{"province": "Beheira", "office": "Palm Marine", "title": "Palm Marine Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Abu generosity", "title": "Abu generosity Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Madamoud", "title": "Madamoud Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Alacalth", "title": "Alacalth Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Azab palace", "title": "Azab palace Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Almosah", "title": "Almosah Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Tnadh", "title": "Tnadh Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Mott sub", "title": "Mott sub Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Alhendao", "title": "Alhendao Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Nasser Revolution", "title": "Nasser Revolution Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "West talented", "title": "West talented Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Farafra", "title": "Farafra Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Enlightening", "title": "Enlightening Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Kalamoon", "title": "Kalamoon Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Winepress Dakhla", "title": "Winepress Dakhla Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Adult", "title": "Adult Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Palace Dakhla Center", "title": "Palace Dakhla Center Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Bulaq New Valley", "title": "Bulaq New Valley Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "New inflows Center", "title": "New inflows Center Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Court", "title": "Court Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Emerging country", "title": "Emerging country Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Paris", "title": "Paris Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "Mott", "title": "Mott Post Office"},
{"province": "New Valley", "office": "\u0627\u0644\u062e\u0627\u0631\u062c\u0629", "title": "\u0627\u0644\u062e\u0627\u0631\u062c\u0629 Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Npan tribal", "title": "Npan tribal Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Nag Alamuesat", "title": "Nag Alamuesat Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Mahamid", "title": "Mahamid Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Mansuriya tribal", "title": "Mansuriya tribal Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Alklh", "title": "Alklh Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Alcajoj", "title": "Alcajoj Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Waterfall", "title": "Waterfall Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Seven East", "title": "Seven East Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Seven West", "title": "Seven West Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Gray sea", "title": "Gray sea Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Alrdesah", "title": "Alrdesah Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Khattara Aswan", "title": "Khattara Aswan Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Aldjaafarh", "title": "Aldjaafarh Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Albesalah", "title": "Albesalah Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Akulait", "title": "Akulait Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Edfu East", "title": "Edfu East Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Edfu", "title": "Edfu Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Edfu tribal", "title": "Edfu tribal Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Abu Rish tribal", "title": "Abu Rish tribal Post Office"},
{"province": "Aswan", "office": "Aswan", "title": "Aswan Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Abu ashes", "title": "Abu ashes Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Hurghada sub", "title": "Hurghada sub Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Or the new Huwaitat", "title": "Or the new Huwaitat Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "El Gouna tourism", "title": "El Gouna tourism Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Red Sea passage", "title": "Red Sea passage Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Ras Gharib Petroleum", "title": "Ras Gharib Petroleum Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Shalateen", "title": "Shalateen Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Safaga _ subsidiary", "title": "Safaga _ subsidiary Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Marsa Alam", "title": "Marsa Alam Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "A second short", "title": "A second short Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Aweyna Red Sea", "title": "Aweyna Red Sea Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Safaga port", "title": "Safaga port Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Ras Gharib sub", "title": "Ras Gharib sub Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Hurghada port", "title": "Hurghada port Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Directorate of Health", "title": "Directorate of Health Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Ahamraoyen", "title": "Ahamraoyen Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Safaga", "title": "Safaga Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Short of the Red Sea", "title": "Short of the Red Sea Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Ras Gharib", "title": "Ras Gharib Post Office"},
{"province": "Red Sea", "office": "Hurghada", "title": "Hurghada Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Majabrh", "title": "Majabrh Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Ketkath", "title": "Ketkath Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Dar es Salaam Peace Center", "title": "Dar es Salaam Peace Center Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Ahlgrezac", "title": "Ahlgrezac Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "El Usayrat established center", "title": "El Usayrat established center Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Godmother Abydos", "title": "Godmother Abydos Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Asalaa", "title": "Asalaa Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Tleihat", "title": "Tleihat Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Sheikh Marzouq", "title": "Sheikh Marzouq Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Alsoamah West", "title": "Alsoamah West Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Zouk East", "title": "Zouk East Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Alajabirat", "title": "Alajabirat Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Algelawih", "title": "Algelawih Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Belina", "title": "Belina Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Albarba", "title": "Albarba Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Batakh", "title": "Batakh Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Adva", "title": "Adva Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Akhmim", "title": "Akhmim Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Sohag", "title": "Sohag Post Office"},
{"province": "Sohag", "office": "Sohag sub", "title": "Sohag sub Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Reseda", "title": "Reseda Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Dandara", "title": "Dandara Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "The main Dishna", "title": "The main Dishna Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Bahgoura", "title": "Bahgoura Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Children Amr", "title": "Children Amr Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "El Usayrat", "title": "El Usayrat Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Halfaya nautical", "title": "Halfaya nautical Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Asamta", "title": "Asamta Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Manor Nagagerh", "title": "Manor Nagagerh Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Rahmaniyah tribal country b", "title": "Rahmaniyah tribal country b Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Home", "title": "Home Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Unguarded Qena", "title": "Unguarded Qena Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Beekeeper", "title": "Beekeeper Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Supervising", "title": "Supervising Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Abnoud", "title": "Abnoud Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Abu Manna nautical", "title": "Abu Manna nautical Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Abu Tesht main", "title": "Abu Tesht main Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Abu Shusha", "title": "Abu Shusha Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "The main Qena", "title": "The main Qena Post Office"},
{"province": "Qena", "office": "Arabs Sabha", "title": "Arabs Sabha Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Navigation", "title": "Navigation Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Sidi Abu pilgrims", "title": "Sidi Abu pilgrims Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Imari facility", "title": "Imari facility Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Qurna", "title": "Qurna Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Karnak Luxor", "title": "Karnak Luxor Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Baghdadi", "title": "Baghdadi Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Blindness", "title": "Blindness Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Tourism Market", "title": "Tourism Market Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Zinnia tribal", "title": "Zinnia tribal Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Tod", "title": "Tod Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Aloqasrata Airport", "title": "Aloqasrata Airport Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Manshyet Nuba", "title": "Manshyet Nuba Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "El Bayadeya", "title": "El Bayadeya Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Tribal Qamola", "title": "Tribal Qamola Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Lentoids", "title": "Lentoids Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Dabayaa", "title": "Dabayaa Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Cairo Sporting Club", "title": "Cairo Sporting Club Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "_ Second Abbasid", "title": "_ Second Abbasid Post Office"},
{"province": "Luxor", "office": "Luxor", "title": "Luxor Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Ministry of Tourism", "title": "Ministry of Tourism Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Ministry of Foreign Affairs", "title": "Ministry of Foreign Affairs Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Cairo traffic", "title": "Cairo traffic Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Tenth District", "title": "Tenth District Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Republican Palace dome", "title": "Republican Palace dome Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Ministry of Education", "title": "Ministry of Education Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Ramses", "title": "Ramses Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Divans", "title": "Divans Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Faggala", "title": "Faggala Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Garden City", "title": "Garden City Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Mohamed Farid", "title": "Mohamed Farid Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Abbasid", "title": "Abbasid Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Parliament", "title": "Parliament Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Television", "title": "Television Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Liberation complex", "title": "Liberation complex Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Ministries", "title": "Ministries Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Bab El Louk", "title": "Bab El Louk Post Office"},
{"province": "Cairo", "office": "Cairos main", "title": "Cairos main Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "City Arts", "title": "City Arts Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Central Ahram", "title": "Central Ahram Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Student", "title": "Student Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Western Urban", "title": "Western Urban Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Queen", "title": "Queen Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Urban East", "title": "Urban East Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Giza station", "title": "Giza station Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Mohammed Island", "title": "Mohammed Island Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Recruitment Giza", "title": "Recruitment Giza Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Provision of Giza", "title": "Provision of Giza Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Munib", "title": "Munib Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Teresa brief", "title": "Teresa brief Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Giza fourth", "title": "Giza fourth Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Paternoster Macki", "title": "Paternoster Macki Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Spring Gizy", "title": "Spring Gizy Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Sunday market", "title": "Sunday market Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Tourism Pyramid", "title": "Tourism Pyramid Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Giza second", "title": "Giza second Post Office"},
{"province": "Giza", "office": "Giza first", "title": "Giza first Post Office"},
... removed
{"province": "Assiut", "office": "Recruitment of Assiut", "title": "Recruitment of Assiut Post Office"}
]
```

Comment: I know Scrapy is the ideal choice for this. I appreciate your thoughtful advice. The thing is, I'm attempting to learn how to integrate sophisticated logic into promises in node.js.

Comment: I will try it by node.js in tonight.

Comment: @robots.txt, I tested it by cheerio but it do not work due to the web site should be render if not do not display table in html. So I try it by puppeteer. it can parsing with headless: false mode. It means rendering mode. It succussed root level parsing. But It has a problem error was "(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected." due to too many async/await loop call. Sorry I can't address this problem.